# Binary to decimal exercise at school

Tags: c++, visual-c++, binary, decimal

So we are learning c++ in school and our teacher told us to make a program converting binary to decimal numbers.

This is what i wrote in main:

```
int i = 0, e = 0,n = 00001111 , c;
while (n > 0)
{
    cout << "n= " << n << endl << "e= " << e << endl;

    c = n % 2;
    n = n / 10;
    if (c == 1)
    {
        e = e + (int)pow(c * 2, i);
    }
    i++;
}
cout << e << endl;

system("pause");
```

output is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ51z.png)

My question is why is n=585, when i wrote 00001111?

Also sorry if the tags are misleading. I am new at this.

Comment: Already did but the value of n is 585 the second i give it a value when declaring it. Also I am not that experienced with the debugger.

Comment: 00001111 is octal, not decimal.

Comment: So the compiler reads 00001111 as octal? It is supposed to be an 8 bit binary number but written as a decimal so it can be divided by 10.Is there a way i can force the compiler to read the value as a decimal?

Comment: if your compiler is compatible with c++14 you can follow the link I included with my answer and use the notation : 0b1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

00001111 in octal is equal to 585 in decimal.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Watch your leading zeros !